# generating images to specific shape using bigGAN

Tags: python, tensorflow, alphablending

basically im using tensorflow and pretrained weights to generate a random image

here is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load the BigGAN 512 model from TensorFlow Hub
module_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/deepmind/biggan-512/2'
module = hub.KerasLayer(module_url)

# Generate a random noise vector of shape (1, 128)
z = tf.random.normal([1, 128])

# Set the truncation value and category index for the BigGAN 512 model
truncation = 0.4
y = tf.one_hot([22], 1000)  # Example: Generate an image of a fire truck (category index 22)

# Generate an image tensor of shape (1, 512, 512, 3) using the BigGAN 512 model and the noise vector
outputs = module(dict(y=y, z=z, truncation=truncation))

# Convert the image tensor to a NumPy array and then to a PIL image
image_array = np.array(outputs[0])
image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image_array * 255))

# Save the generated image
image.save('generated_image.png')
```

it generates image and saves it
but here i want to achieve one more thing
can we generate image in a specific shape

for instance  there is a masked image of a certain shape
can we generate image of that shape

i tried blending the generated images to the masked iamge shape
but the output isn't satisfactory its just blending the image rather than filling the image into the mask

any other possible solution for this scenario  ?

Comment: you didn't use OpenCV. why tag it?

Comment: though i havent used the questions actually is 
"can we generate image in a specific shape

for instance there is a masked image of a certain shape can we generate image of that shape

i tried blending the generated images to the masked iamge shape but the output isn't satisfactory its just blending the image rather than filling the image into the mask"
so asking for suggestions based on the mentioned tags (blending or any other)

Comment: please use some punctuation.